# Change data length using SSIS DerivedColumn

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, ssis-2012, derived-column

I´m reading `.csv` file to paste into `sql table` but I get advertesiment into a column

[image]

It occurse because my destination table have "MOLDE" with `string(50)` and source have `string(255)`

How can I change "MOLDE" length to get only 50 first values

So I create derived column and I try to use substring, but it keep getting length 255 
[image]

What can I do there?. Regards

----UPDATE----

I´m resolve it as answer comment but I still getting Advertisiment Icon like this:
[image]

Is it posible to remove it?

Comment: How about `LEFT(MOLDE,50)` ?

Comment: Yes it works, but cann you view my update in my question please? @bjones

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try casting to `DT_STR` with length equal 50

```
(DT_STR,50,1252)SUBSTRING(MOLDE,1,50)
```

OR

```
(DT_STR,50,1252)LEFT(MOLDE,50)
```

*Note that you have to map the derived column to the destination instead of the original column , if warning still appearing just double click on the destination to refresh metadata*

**Reference**

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/expressions/cast-ssis-expression

**UPDATE 1**

After reading your comment i think the warning still appearing because you have selected derived column option to replace the original column which caused this conflict, just change the option `Replace 'MOLDE'` to `Add New Column` and map the derived column to the destination column.

Or make sure that the destination is reading `MOLDE` column from the derived column component not the Source column, openning Destination with advanced editor may help.

Comment: I do it, and I double click on the destinaion but I still getting warning

Comment: What is the warning message. Handover the mouse on the warning mark to see it

Comment: may be it is another one

Comment: I check it and is the same warning as I post

Comment: Check that you have used the derived column not the source.

Answer (score 1):

Right click your warning icon, chose Show Advanced Editor, input and output properties tab, check your column length there.